# Group data from 2d array by column and count or sum other columns

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I am build a multidimension array from data that has a multiple entries but some entries have the same value;

```
id      name      delivery#  weight    time
--------------------------------------------
12      test      112233     45        now
13      test      112234     456       now
14      testA     112245     33        later
15      testB     334421     334       later
...
...
```

and foreach id I push to array like so;

```
array_push($arraydata, array(
"id" => $id, 
"name" => $name,
"delivery" => $delivery,
"weight" => $weight,
"time" => $time
));
```

and later I use to loop through it;

```
foreach($arraydata as $arraydataItem) {

//do stuff...
//test appears twice - echo count & delivery values
//testA once - echo count
//testB once - echo count

}
```

Basically I want check how many times the same name value appears and add the weight values together for a total.

As then for each "delivery" with the same "name" divide the delivery weight by the total weight of "name" and get the percentage which I will use for calculating the percentage of the total cost of "name"..

Comment: Try to use  key => value in foreach loop `foreach($arraydata as $k =>$v) {`

Comment: Where's your SQL query? Also, post the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Actually I am reading each row from a excel spreadsheet..and the array is rendered correctly, just need to do what the question stated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating *that* associative array using `array_push()`, you should create a multidimensional array like this,

```
$arraydata[$name][] = array('id' => $id, 'delivery' => $delivery, 'weight' => $weight, 'time' => $time);
```

And as per your question,

> Basically I want check how many times the same name value appears and add the weight values together for a total.

Simply use a `foreach` loop to loop through `$arraydata` array and display count and total weight associated for each name, like this:

```
foreach($arraydata as $key => $arraydataItem){
    // Display count and total weight associated for each name
    echo $key . ": (count: " . count($arraydataItem) . ", total weight: " . array_sum(array_column($arraydataItem,'weight')) . ")<br />";
}
```

This will output:

```
test: (count: 2, total weight: 501)
testA: (count: 1, total weight: 33)
testB: (count: 1, total weight: 334)
```

Moreover, you can tweak this code to fulfil your further requirements.

---

**Note:** If you want to see the structure of `$arraydata` array, do `var_dump($arraydata);`